# Compile error in third party API - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I tried using a few hash APIs but it gives compile error. I tried 2 different hash APIs and 2 different IDEs and compiler but it gives the same errors. It looks like a linker error. Often there is a "unresolved external externals" or "undefined to" compile error. How can I fix compile error?

**test.cpp:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "xxHash-0.7.4/xxhash.h"

int main()
{
    const char test[] = "srgsdf";
    XXH64_hash_t seed = 545244;

    XXH64_hash_t test_xxhash = XXH64(test, strlen(test), seed);

    std::cout << test_xxhash;

    return 0;
}
```

**Error List:**

```
LNK1120 -   unresolved externals    
LNK2019 -   unresolved external symbol _XXH64 referenced in function _main
```

XXHash64 on Visual Studio 2019 - 16.6.2:
 [XXHash64 on Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UwUI.png)

XXHash64 API on Code::Blocks - 20.03:
[XXHash64 API on Code::Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2GPM.png)

[Hash Library](https://github.com/stbrumme/hash-library) on Visual Studio 2019 - 16.6.2: [Hash Library on Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfSPa.png)

[Hash Library](https://github.com/stbrumme/hash-library) on Code::Blocks - 20.03: [Hash Library on Code::Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGwS.png)

Comment: I did not touch the linker settings. All of them are from default settings.

Comment: Welcome to SO! kindly share code snippet instead of screenshots. You can read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more.

Comment: I added the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A likely reason is that your project is missing `xxhash.c` in its list of source files to compile. Each `*.c` file becomes an object file, which is linked during the last stage. So without it, no symbol defined in `xxhash.c` is ever created.

Another way to solve this issue is to `#define XXH_INLINE_ALL` just before `#include "xxhash.h"`. This will *inline* the code, as if it was present in the local source file, and as a consequence, it will not need to link to another object file. Inlining is also good for performance on small data, but increases binary size.